# :not selector not working on ul class - alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've made my header and drop down nav and have mini dividers between each word - the exception was the last word. But on the last word, I had a dropdown. I tried putting the dropdown in a li class called roster, and did `:not(.roster)` where I had `:not(:last-child)`. Now it is as if I didn't even have the not selector there. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1tqydkp/1/).

So, back to my question... Are there any alternatives to the :not selector ? I have read that it doesn't work on Internet Explorer 8, but I am using Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.118. Here is my code:

***RELEVANT HTML***

```
    <div id="nav-clearfix">
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="nav-pages">
                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SPONSORS</a></li>
                <li class="roster"><a href="#">ROSTER</a>
                    <ul class="fallback">
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Competitive</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Editors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Feeding</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

***CSS***

```
  #header_logo-clearfix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 30px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #02236a;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#nav-clearfix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #02236a;
}

#nav {
  margin-left: 35%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nav-pages {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav-pages li:not(.roster) a:after {
  content: "";
  /* width: 0px; */
  background: white;
  margin-left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  color: white;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 15px;
}

.nav-pages li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#nav {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav a {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#nav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: akk 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s
}

#nav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  background: #02236a;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  width: 80px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color:#444;
}

nav ul li ul.fallback {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul.fallback {
  display: block;
}

ul.dropdown li {
   position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown li ul {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px; /* assign the correct value of the top line height */
   left: 0px;
}

.fallback li{
      margin-left: 10px;

}

.fallback{
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    $('nav li').hover(
      function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    },
      function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
    }
);
```

Comment: Why is `:not` appended to the `li` element?  Shouldn't it be the `ul` element which actually has that class?

Comment: @billynoah oops, i'll fix it up now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just change the selector from:

```
.nav-pages li:not(.roster) a:after {
```

to:

```
.nav-pages > li > a:after {
```

And to remove the final border you can override the preceeding CSS:

```
.nav-pages > li:last-child > a:after {
   border: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/17rvm9cg/

Regarding your question about an alternative to `:not`, my approach is generally to apply the style I want and then override it on elements as illustrated above.

Comment: it seems to just changes the lists to vertical

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Take a look at the jfiddle and let me know.

Comment: i must not've seen the second part of code you put in. it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do this give every `ul li a:after` the style and set the `fallback li a:after` to `display:none`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1tqydkp/3/)